# Re-size Event on div captured by innerHTML hover and user can't grab the re-size triangle

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please no jQuery - only JavaScript or better yet simply CSS

You can see the problem here: Try to resize div.

I have a series of  div tags that have dynamic content and need to be re-sizable by users. When the inner content has a hover event,it grabs the event and the user can't re-size. The dynamic content can be any size -usually bigger than the outer div.  I'd love to solve this with css, but adding padding or margins to the outer div does not seem to help.  This only has to work on latest Firefox and Chrome. This is not the exact code, but it's show the problem - at least in FireFox:

```
<head>
    <style>
        #inner:hover {
            display:block;
            color:#FF00FF;
            background-color:grey;
            width:500px;
            height:400px;
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<div id="outer" style="resize:both;width:20px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="inner" style="width:90px;height:90px;">
        foobar<br>
        foobar<br>
        foobar<br>
        foobar<br>
        foobar<br>
        foobar
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your current javascript to indicated what you have so far. A fiddle would be preferred.

Comment: here is a fiddle to get you started. add your js in lower left and then click `Run` to test it. Once satisfied click `Update` and the url will change. Edit your answer to add the link. It sounds like the `resize` control of the outer div doesn't function when the inner div has a hover event attached to it.

Comment: MrTsherman, you mentioned no fiddle url.  But I created one: http://jsfiddle.net/ledipo/ETnmf/   There is no javascript. I have not tried yet to capture the events.

Comment: Does anyone haveany ideas? See fiddle for a visual of the problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/ledipo/ETnmf